# NullPointer when using Log class

Tags: android, logging

I was under the impression that the Log class as compared to using View related class like Toast, should be able to display null if an object or variable is null, rather than crashing the application.

Can someone please explain to me why this is so?

I don't know why I have to write a null checker before performing simple logging.

```
enter public void onClick(final View view) {
    busy.set(View.VISIBLE);
    final String email = this.email.get();
    final String password = this.password.get();

    if(!isValidEmail(email)) {
        Snackbar.make(view,"email is invalid" , Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        busy.set(View.GONE);
        return;
    }
    Log.d("PASSWORD", password);
```

Above is a simple code snippet, in this scenario, the app crashes when the password is null during the logging. In this case, i would have to put an if statement to check for null before actually logging.

Comment: *why this is so?* this is an question that no one an actually answer properly. they might have check for null values and handled themselves, but they decided not to and this is the reality now.

Comment: please include your code also with question

Comment: A second form of Log.d does permit @Nullable for the 2nd parameter: `Log.d("PASSWORD",password,null)` where `password` could be null.  The third parameter is an optional `Throwable` object which is also @Nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Log.d()` format is wrong, you are passing a `null` value to the message of the Log. the correct format would be:

```
Log.d("PASSWORD", "LOG MESSAGE" + password);
```